# Disable/enable extended standby mode in Xperia smartphones

Tags: android, sony

Does anyone know whether it is possible to programatically enable/disable Sony specific extended standby mode in Xperia P? If yes, what code I have to use?
I am going to create android widget to switch profiles, but I need to have handling extended standby mode in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sony specific standby mode API in Xperia P open to public.